# How do I sort an array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Input has to taken by the user. My code is given below. Why does it only output zeroes? What is the solution?

Output of the program is `0 0 0 0` (total number of input taken).

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class atlast {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = input.nextInt();
        int[] array = new int[107];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            array[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        Arrays.sort(array);

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Java programming conventions use identifiers in camelCase, with classes starting with upper case letters (AtLast) and variables and methods starting with lower case.

Comment: You have initialised array with more than space. So this is causing problem as explained by @Mhamad in answer. You can avoid it by assigning the input value like 
int n = input.nextInt();
int[] array = new int[n];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int[] array = new int[107];
```

You are initializing a table that contains 107 value of 0.
So, if the `n` is small, the first elements will be 0.

To see the result replace n in the last loop by 107 and you will see the values

Answer (score 0):

You initialized an array with size 107 which implies there are 107 zeroes in the array initially before accepting the input from the user. Since there are four zeroes in the output, you must have taken 4 values for input. So there are four non-zero values and 103 zero values in the array. When you apply **Arrays.sort** 103 zeros comes before 4 non-zero values. Hence when you print n values (which is 4 in this case) you get only zeroes.
You could use **ArrayList** instead so that numbers will be initialized only when user enters it.